# Nestjs: Set global prefix for dynamic modules

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to set a global prefix for a **dynamic module** that I'm going to provide as **npm dependency**.

It works fine when I'm running the project as a **stand alone** app, but when I integrate the dependency in another Nestjs project, the prefix doesn't show as part of the url.

Any clue what is the reason of such behavior?

Also I tried to set the global prefix in the main project, but it was applied to all apis including those of the dynamic module.

Is there a way to set different global prefixes one for the dependency and another for the project using it?